# Haskell unwrap Maybe keep polymorphism

Tags: haskell, option-type, unwrap

Haskell beginner here again. If I want to unwrap a `Maybe` type and want to keep it abstract I would use:

```
fUnwrap :: Maybe a -> a 
fUnwrap (Just n) = n 
fUnwrap Nothing = ???
```

No matter what I do with `Nothing`, compiler keeps nagging about being more specific on what to do with `Nothing`... Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Well this is just not a good idea. You can add a default value for a `Nothing`, or you can ignore that line, but then you will get an error in case it is a `Maybe`.

Comment: Is there a larger problem you’re trying to solve here? If so, could you describe it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is logical. The compiler explects a value of type `a`, but here there is no value you can provide, since `a` can be anything (a `Bool`, `Int`, `[Int]`, `Maybe Int`, etc.).

This is not that much a programming problem, it is more a *design* problem: what do you want to do in case it is a `Nothing`? There are some options here:

1. providing a default value, so then the signature is:

   ```
   fUnwrap :: a -> Maybe a -> a 
   fUnwrap _ (Just n) = n
   fUnwrap d Nothing = d
   ```
2. we raise an error in case it is `Nothing` (we can do this both be leaving the line out, or raising an error explicitly, although in the latter case we can specify a reason):

   ```
   fUnwrap :: Maybe a -> a
   fUnwrap (Just n) = n
   fUnwrap Nothing = error "Nothing has no value"
   ```
3. we return `undefined`:

   ```
   fUnwrap :: Maybe a -> a
   fUnwrap (Just n) = n
   fUnwrap Nothing = undefined
   ```

   [**`undefined :: a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:undefined) is an object that raises an error if it is evaluated. It is thus a special case of `error`, but we "postpone" evaluation such that if the value is not necessary, we do not get an error.

But personally I think the first approach is advisable here, since function signatures do not specify that these can raise an error, it thus results in code that might fail, without having a hint that it can.

A `Maybe a` is typically used as the result type of a computation that can "fail": in case it succeeds, it returns `Just x` (with `x` the result), and otherwise it returns `Nothing`.

You can use for example `do` notation to construct a `Maybe a` out of a chain of computations that can fail. For example:

```
foo :: Int -> Maybe Int
foo x = do
    y <- someComputation x
    otherComputation y
```

with here fore example `someComputation, otherComputation :: Int -> Maybe Int`.

Comment: Very clear Willem! What I actually needed is your example 1. Just don't want users confronted with Nothing and catch it by using a default value, as you indicated. Also thanks very much for putting this in context and indicate the other options I have.

Comment: What is wrong with restricting Maybe to Monoids? unwrapping Nothing would return mempty

Comment: @AnthonyRaimondo: yes, but then this thus only works for `Monoid`s, since "raw" `Int`s are for example not `Monoid`s (well `Sum`, and `Product` are), this would thus result in a lot of wrapping and unwrapping in monoid constructors.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem makes sense, thanks didnt realize Int was not a monoid!

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible as your function is written. Since the function is pure, you cannot return an a as your only input is Nothing.

The beauty of Maybe is that you don't need to "unwrap" it. You can use the fmap function to operate on the wrapped data only if it exists,  and implicitly do nothing in the Nothing case.

Comment: I do realize that I can operate on Maybe types, but the point is the output to eg. JSON, XML. I don't want Just's and Nothing's in there, but actually values or " ".

Comment: @Madderote in that case use `maybe " " show`. Always ask directly what you want to know. :)